# Completely disable ROS from logging to log files?

Tags: python, c++, logging, ros, bazel

I am trying to disable ROS from creating any ROS files but I haven't been able to find any solution that actually works.

I tried
`log4j.threshold=OFF` as described in http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole but that doesn't work for me.

I also tried setting `export ROSOUT_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING=True` but that didn't help either.

I am using ROS melodic and I am using bazel to build the package not CMake.

I am completely stuck is there any other way for ROS to not generate any log files.

Comment: Check out this discussion: https://answers.ros.org/question/9627/how-can-i-completely-disable-writing-logs-to-filesystem/

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single "good" way to completely disable all logging, however, it can be worked around somewhat well.

First, you can stop `rosout` from being spun up with `'rosmaster --core`. This will strictly start the `roscore` and not the output.

For `roscpp` logging you can add an extra compile flag `-DROSCONSOLE_MIN_SEVERITY=5 ${ROS_COMPILE_FLAGS}` and then rebuild your system. This will *mostly* disable cpp logging, with slight exception; one of the internal loggers seems to bypass this.

For `rospy` there is a logging config file located at `/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/etc/ros/python_logging.conf` and `/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/share/rosgraph/conf/python_logging.conf`. If you delete these files python will skip logging complete. I should note that I don't recommend this approach.

Another solution that might be helpful is to simply set the logging directory to a temporary storage system. `export ROS_LOG_OUT=/tmp/roslogs`. This will still write to the log files, but all entries will be erased from your drive on reboots.